# What method should i use to analyze the effects of rainfall and temperature on birds?

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, anova, ecology

Which method should I use to analyze the effect of temperature and rainfall on birds?

I need to analyze the effects of rainfall and temperature on Frugivorous birds in a wildlife reserve. We don't actually have to run the numbers but still explain what method we'd use and how to carry it out. I was thinking of using ANOVA or Shannon-Wiener Index but don't know if they're correct

Comment: Can you describe your measurements? What effects on the birds do you measure?

Comment: Over what time frame?  Are you measuring population?  Some behavior?